# Function::apply without overriding the receiver

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
obj =
  test: -> this.doSomething()

args = [...]

try
  obj.test.apply undefined, args
catch e
  console.error e
```

The ideal outcome is `obj.test.apply` **not** throwing an error. Though I can't find any way to spread an array across a function call (aka `Function::apply`) without overriding the receiver (aka `this` inside `obj.test`).

Is this not possible?

Comment: `obj.test.apply obj, args` ...?

Comment: What error does it throw? Is `doSomething` bound to an object other than `obj`? Is `doSomething` a valid function and a property of `obj` or its prototype?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) then just tell it what `this` is supposed to be:

```
obj.test.apply obj, args
```

But since this is CoffeeScript, you can hide all that behind a [splat](http://coffeescript.org/#splats):

```
obj.test(args...)
```

That becomes `obj.test.apply(obj, args)` in the JavaScript version.

For example:

```
args = [ 1 ]
obj.test(args...) # same as obj.test(1)

args = [ 1, 2 ]
obj.test(args...) # same as obj.test(1, 2)
```

You can also use a splat in the function definition to make it variadic:

```
obj =
  test: (args...) -> # do things with the `args` array
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/1kgzc1kn/

Comment: Unfortunately, that still overrides the `this` that is currently bound to the function. And it isn't the object that holds it. It's a private object.

Comment: @aleclarson That's not obvious from the example that you've given.

Comment: Your comment has nothing to do with your question. If you say `obj.test()`  then `this` is going to be `obj` inside `test`. Maybe you could ask the question that you want answered.